# Batch zipping multiple files in single directory

Tags: batch-file

I need to make batch script, which will work this way:

There is a folder with one hundred files. I need to make a script which is zipping every 4 files into single archive. Then all created archives must be zipped into one, big archive file. That must be all done by one script.

I tried to make it, but I haven't idea how to make it this way.

This is what I wrote first:

```
@ECHO ON
SET SourceDir=C:\Users\Ridaan\Documents\sobol
SET DestDir=C:\folder\Destination

CD /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN ('DIR /B /A-D "%SourceDir%"') DO (
    7z.exe a "%DestDir%\%%~NF.zip" "%SourceDir%\%%~NXF"
)
EXIT
```

And second:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
robocopy C:\folder\Destination /COPY:DAT /V /XO /NJH /NP /R:1000 /W:10
7z u -mx9 "C:\folder\End.7z" "C:\folder\Destination"
rmdir C:\folder\End\ /Q /S

:END
pause
```

Comment: The idea is that you attempt the task. There seems to be nothing in your code which attempts to select groups of four files, so until you've researched and attempted it your question is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea of counting files and

- calculating the int of count/4 for the zip number
- the modulus%4 for the file number (0..3) to determine if it's a new zip to create or to append to the zip.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\11\SO_53251220.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set Cnt=0
Set "SrcDir=X:\Your\Path"
For /F "delims=" %%A in ('Dir /B/A-D "%SrcDir%\*"') do (
  Set /A "File=Cnt%%4,Zip=Cnt/4,Cnt+=1"
  Echo Cnt=!Cnt! File=!File! Zip=!Zip! File=%%A
)
```